# Elasticsearch X-Pack builtin cluster alerts email

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I'm running ES 6.4 with X-Pack installed.
There are builtin alerts for cluster awareness:

[image]

I'm receiving email alerts for cluster severity, shards allocation etc which are coming in from "X-pack Admin" with one of my email addresses. These watchers are most probably the origin.
Where are these Watchers taking the destination and From email addresses from?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

This is one of the default watcher alert, and email can be set in Kibana -> Management -> Advanced Settings -> Admin email